# Detect changes to ScrollView height using only its node handle in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, layout, resize, scrollview

I have a ScrollView that, depending on user input, can change in height. I want to be able to detect whenever those changes happen, but I don't have access to the component itself so I cannot just pass in a callback 'onContentSizeChanged', all I have is the ref & node handle returned by findNodeHandle(scrollViewRef)

Due to implementation details, it has to be this way. However, I've been struggling to find any material/posts online regarding this approach to handling layout changes. I don't even need to know the new layout, just that a change happened so it can trigger a re-measure of elements inside the ScrollView.

Is there any way I can accomplish what I want to accomplish using only the ref/node handle and without having to pass any props to the ScrollView? Thanks!

So far, I have no idea where to start on this problem (besides modifying react-native with `patch-package`). I looked through the documentation and the ScrollView component code and I couldn't find anything that might help.

ResizeObserver of course would have been neat, but my code needs to run on iOS, Android and the web.

Comment: How about wrapping the ScrollView you don't control in a View that you do?

Comment: @Abe that is really good idea and should works.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a possibility to accomplish what you're trying to do using the `onLayout` prop provided by React Native.

You can do something like this :

```
import { findNodeHandle } from 'react-native'

const scrollViewRef = useRef(null)
const scrollViewNode = findNodeHandle(scrollViewRef.current)

const handleLayoutChange = (event) => {
    // Do whatever you want on layout change here
}

<ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} onLayout={handleLayoutChange}>
    {/* ... */}
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: A key part of my problem is, as mentioned in the question, I need to be able to detect changes `"without having to pass any props to the ScrollView"` (besides the `ref` prop).
Basically, the code I'm writing lives in a hook, and the only input it should take is the ref to the ScrollView, nothing else. This is important for keeping the API simple.